# can I write to CSV form orderdict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csvwriter

what is the problem with my below code
the error said that is not writeable

```
with open('F:\learning\coding\python learning\jadi excersisse\work with files\grades_for_exercise.csv') as f:
        myFile=csv.reader(f)
        person_mean=OrderedDict()
        for row in myFile:
            name=row[0]
            person_grades=[]
            for number in row[1:]:
                person_grades.append(int(number))
            person_mean[name]=mean(person_grades)
        print(list(person_mean.items()))
with open ('F:\learning\coding\python learning\jadi excersisse\work with files\one_result.csv') as csvfile:
        csvwriter=csv.writer(csvfile)
        csvwriter.writerows((person_mean))
```

i need the data be witten in csv file

Comment: Please, post full traceback you get. Also I would [convert windows paths to raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/4046632).

Comment: Probably you mean  `csvwriter.writerows(person_mean.items())`

Comment: it did not work, same error appear that says "not writable"

Comment: Please, post full traceback, along with sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the document of open () function, I have found the problem.
It is necessary to write the mode in open function. When I added the mode "w" for write in to the file, the problem  was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand this is how you read and write csv fiels in python

```
import csv

data = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]

def save_in_csv(data):
    with open("your_csv_file.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(data)

def open_csv():
    with open("your_csv_file.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)

save_in_csv(data)
open_csv()
```

i hope this helps you

Comment: what kind of data can i use in writer.writerrows(data) ?

Comment: writerows cann write a list of rows and a row is a list in it self. for more detail you can have a look in the doc off the module because they descripe it far better then i am. Link to the docs: [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)